# How can I find out who's logged on to database?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to rename a database in SSMS and I get this error:

`The database could not be exclusively locked to perform the operation`

So how can I find out who or what is using this database?  I don't want to go and change anything without knowing what is going to be effected.

Thanks

Comment: run sp_who to see what sessions are logged on to databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below shows what database has users connected, what username, and machine name attached.

```
SELECT @@ServerName AS SERVER
 ,NAME
 ,login_time
 ,last_batch
 ,getdate() AS DATE
 ,STATUS
 ,hostname
 ,program_name
 ,nt_username
 ,loginame
FROM sys.databases d
LEFT JOIN sysprocesses sp ON d.database_id = sp.dbid
WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 0   AND 4
 AND loginame IS NOT NULL 
 order by hostname
```

[image]